# WordPress Post Title Maximum Character Lenght

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress based application which has to accommodate very long post titles. Do I understand correctly that the WP post title is limited by the actual VARCHAR column type (65,535 bytes for MySQL after 5.0.3) and such long titles will not affect the performance?

I just made some preliminary tests and it seems that long titles are not an issue, does anyone know any adverse effects ?

(note: please note this is not a typical blog site, the WP is used as a custom CMS in this case)

Comment: Might be duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20870615/18363980). Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72185967/18363980).

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am going to answer my own question unless someone proves me wrong.

> Since the version 3.0 there is no limit in the actual post title
>   character length other that the actual MySql limitation for the
>   "varchar" field. However, if pretty permalinks are used
>   (i.e.:/%category%/%postname%/) then it would be advisable to clean up
>   the possible lengthy url.