# Validating post title and content in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I intend to let users create blog posts via the front end. I need to make sure the post title and content are each less than 100 characters.

Which hook should I hook my validation function to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hook needed is wp_insert_post_data

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data

Comment: hey @henrywright,how to set validation by this code..:D :D :D

Comment: In your custom function, `$data` will be a sanitised array of post data. You can validate the title and content then return it.

Comment: thx. for your reply.but i am not sure.the above action/hook will insert post in database .that is what i want to prevent..from jquery or php :(

Comment: The filter hook is called by the `wp_insert_post()` function prior to inserting into or updating the database. It allows you to **filter** the post data. Hope this helps.

Comment: but how to stop insert post I have made  search to find post_content validate but cant get any solution.

Comment: You should ask this here on Stack Overflow as a new question.

Comment: This can be used for the **sanitization** but not for the **validation** of the post data. Validation is when you can prevent saving data and return an error notice instead, which you cannot do using this filter.

Answer (score 3):

This code makes sure that post title is not empty or longer than 100 characters. You can adjust it to your needs if necessary. The code will work as follows:

- If errors occur while you are creating a new post, the post won't be published and it will remain in auto-draft status (it won't show in the listing);
- If errors occur during the update of the existing post, the `post_title` and `post_status` will not be changed;
- Replace `your_custom_post_type` with your custom post type.

The code:

```
<?php

add_action('save_post_{your_custom_post_type}', 'custom_validate_post', 10, 2);

if (!function_exists('custom_validate_post')) {
    function custom_validate_post(int $post_ID, WP_Post $post): void
    {
        // Exit early if save_post is triggered when trashing the post
        if ($post->post_status === 'trash' || defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
            return;
        }

        $errors = [];

        // Validation filters
        if (empty($post->post_title)) {
            $errors['title'] = 'The title is required';
        }

        if(strlen($post->post_title) > 100) {
            $errors['title'] = 'The title should not be longer than 100 characters';
        }

        // If we have errors lets setup some messages
        if (!empty($errors)) {
            // Save the errors as option
            update_option('post_errors', $errors);

            // admin_notice is create by a $_GET['message'] with a number that wordpress uses to
            // Display the admin message so we will add a filter for replacing default admin message with a redirect
            add_filter('redirect_post_location', function (string $location) {
                // Remove $_GET['message']
                $location = remove_query_arg( 'message', $location );

                // Add our new query sting
                $location = add_query_arg( 'custom_validation', 'failed', $location );

                // Return the location query string
                return $location;
            });
        }
    }
}

// We use this action to get the data before and after the update in order to revert the data if validation fails
add_action('post_updated', 'custom_set_old_post_data_if_error', 10, 3);

if (!function_exists('custom_set_old_post_data_if_error')) {
    function custom_set_old_post_data_if_error(int $post_ID, WP_Post $post_after, WP_Post $post_before)
    {
        // Exit early if post_updated is triggered when trashing the post
        if ($post_after->post_status === 'trash' || $post_after->post_type !== 'your_custom_post_type') {
            return;
        }

        if (empty($post_after->post_title) || strlen($post_after->post_title) > 100) {
            // We must remove this action or it will loop forever since we use wp_update_post below
            remove_action('post_updated', 'custom_set_old_post_data_if_error');


            // Set old `post_title` and `post_status` if validation fails
            wp_update_post(
                [
                    'ID' => $post_after->ID,
                    'post_title' => $post_before->post_title,
                    'post_status' => $post_before->post_status,
                ]
            );

            add_action('post_updated', 'custom_set_old_post_data_if_error');
        }
    }
}

// Add new admin message
add_action( 'admin_notices', function () {
        if (isset($_GET['custom_validation']) && $_GET['custom_validation'] === 'failed') {

        // Get the errors from the option album_errors
        $errors = get_option('post_errors');

        // Now delete the option post errors
        delete_option('post_errors');

        $display = '<div id="notice" class="error"><ul>';

        // Because we are storing as an array we should loop through them
        foreach ( $errors as $error ) {
            $display .= '<li>' . $error . '</li>';
        }

        $display .= '</ul></div>';

        // Finally echo out our display
        echo $display;

        // Add some jQuery
        ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($) {
                $("#title").css({"border": "1px solid red"})
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
});
```

There are couple of things to be aware of:

- if there are posts in trash with the title that is not valid, you won't be able to untrash these posts before changing the title;
- if you want to apply this to all of the posts and not a certain custom post type, use `save_post` hook instead of `save_post_{your_custom_post_type}` and remove `$post_after->post_type !== 'your_custom_post_type'` condition from the code.

Wish you best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Use plugin for that. It will help you needful.

Refer this: http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-title-validation/

OR

Use this code.

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'custom_error_notice' );
function custom_error_notice(){
    global $current_screen, $post;
    if ( $current_screen->parent_base == 'edit' ){
        if((!$post->post_name && !$post_content) && $_GET['post']) {
            wp_redirect(admin_url('post-new.php?empty=1'));
        }
        if($_GET['empty']) echo '<div class="error"><p>Warning - Please fill up all fields correctly!</p></div>';
    }
}
```

- Thanks

Comment: Thank you Anand, with reference to the code, I noticed you hooked to admin_notices. Is this just for the back-end? Don't forget my 'create new post' form is on the front-end.

Comment: But is admin_notices a back-end hook?

Comment: I think yes but have not tested yet. So try it in your code & if not working then find the proper hook.